# Where is the information from 'apt show <packagename>' stored?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, apt-cache

I have the following problem: I wrote a script, that extracts information about the installed packages of my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I am particularly interested in the *source* of the package. This means, that the data of **APT-Sources** from `apt show <packagename>` is crucial for me.

As of now, my script has to call `apt show` for every single installed package which creates an almost unacceptable workload in comparison to how small of a task this should be [the CPU load reaches almost 100%].

I was hoping, that there was some file on the system, that has all the information stored, that is output by `apt show`. Reading and parsing that file should be faster than calling `apt show` thousands of times. Is there such a file?

---

Please note, that I already tried to use `dpkg`and `apt-cache`, but both do not provide the **APT-Sources** information.

---

**edit:** Maybe some elaboration might be useful. My Python script calls `apt list --installed` to get the list of installed packages and parses this output into a list, containing only the package names as strings.

Then it calls `apt show` for every element in this list.

I would have liked, to only have a single file, read **once**, that contains information about the installed packages. I then would have my script parse this file, add the information to the list element and be done in one iteration. My hope was, that reading a large file once and parsing it, is faster than calling a CLI command many hundreds of times.

As such, I assume, that `grep`ing over multiple files multiple times would not really decrease the workload.

Comment: Uh, I don't see anything special in the output of `apt show git | grep Sources` that's not in the output of `apt-cache policy git`.

Comment: @muru This looks more like it. But looking into `/var/cache/apt/` I can't find anything I could directly parse in my script. For example running `grep -r "Sources" *` inside `/var/cache/apt/` gives me nothing. Is there a non-binary file, that would provide the info?

Comment: The output in `APT-Sources` (and in `apt-cache policy`) is essentially the *name* of a file `/var/lib/apt/lists`: Compare output of `grep 'Package: git' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages -l | awk -F'[/_]' '{printf "http://%s/%s %s/%s %s %s\n", $6, $7, $9, $10, $11, $12}'`

Comment: If you're using Python and you run `apt list`, **you're already doing it wrong**. APT has a Python API: https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/ What do you need it for, anyway?

Comment: I basically implemented a system to watch over the installed packages in our landscape, collecting information about them and checking, if some of those are installed with a wrong version. Since some of these packages come from our own intern repositories, it is necessary to know, where the package came from. Originally the landscape ran a SLES distro, but we were going to switch to Ubuntu in the near future (with SLES, `rpm` and `zypper`where enough to get all the information we could wish for).

Comment: **But** with the information that APT-Sources is basically the name of these files, you have given me my answer I was looking for. :) Sorry for being so slow to understand how this worked. Now it's clear. Also thanks for the Python API link. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I basically implemented a system to watch over the installed packages in our landscape, collecting information about them and checking, if some of those are installed with a wrong version. Since some of these packages come from our own intern repositories, it is necessary to know, where the package came from.

Using the Python APT API:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import apt
cache = apt.cache.Cache()
for pkg in cache:
    if pkg.is_installed:
         name = pkg.name
         version = pkg.installed.version
         origins = [o.site for o in pkg.installed.origins if o.site]
         print(name, version, origins)
```

Example output:

```
$ ./foo.py| head
a11y-profile-manager-indicator 0.1.10-0ubuntu3 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
account-plugin-facebook 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com', 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
account-plugin-flickr 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com', 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com', 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
accountsservice 0.6.40-2ubuntu11.3 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
acl 2.2.52-3 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
acpi-support 0.142 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
acpid 1:2.0.26-1ubuntu2 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
activity-log-manager 0.9.7-0ubuntu23.16.04.1 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
adduser 3.113+nmu3ubuntu4 ['jp.archive.ubuntu.com', 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
ls /var/lib/apt/lists
```

depend on the repository and section, for example to gather data about `wget` in `main` section for `amd64` architecture you can use:

```
grep -A20 "Package: wget" /var/lib/apt/lists/*_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
```

or as Muru suggested use `awk` for more flexible result:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' -v pkg=wget '$2 == pkg' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64*
```

- Using `RS` (Record separator) we can easily get all data related to our package.

Note that `apt` also uses some binary caches made of above files to increase the speed of its queries, these caches are located here:

```
ls /var/cache/apt/
```

Comment: I'd suggest something like `awk -v RS='\n\n' -v pkg=wget '$2 == pkg' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages` - easier to customize the package name if you replace `wget` with a variable.

Comment: Thank your for your response. Maybe you can clarify the following: Wouldn't I need to have some prior knowledge about where the package came from to use this `grep` command? Also the output matches that of `apt-cache` show, which does not suffice for me. I was hoping for a single file that I could read in and parse. The `grep` command with the glob looks like a potentially unnecessary number of file-reading to me, if I could just read one single file once instead.

Comment: @AlexPoth grep everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists`

Comment: @muru `grep`ing everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` yields a long output. Parsing that one, would be a lot a work as well and also that output is not restricted to the one, where the package was actually installed from, but to every source this package might have. Also the overhead of parsing everything for every package persists.

Comment: @AlexPoth look into something like this: `*_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_*_binary-amd64_Packages` it will decrease your search into all sections of `dist-updats` for `amd64`, otherwise read a little bit about repositories in Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexPoth also if you're going to use `grep` the `-h` option might be helpful to you (search without including the file names in output)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ravexina I think I found my answer, combined with the comments on my question. :)